# Git remote ssh url

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I'm trying to get git up running on a Windows server.

I have installed winssh and git on the server and now I wanted to test if everything is nice and cool. But it ain't.

I have the following url in the config file:

```
username@domain:GitRepo/QRCode.git
```

But I get the following error when I try to push:

```
does not appear to be a repository
```

I've created the repo like this:

```
mkdir QRCode.git
cd QRCode.git
git --bare init
```

And I can see all the git stuff is there at: "C:\GitRepo\QRCode.git"

I have also tried to change the URL to:

```
username@domain:c/GitRepo/QRCode.git
```

without any luck.

Comment: have you tried changing `/` to double `/` or a `\\` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. I tried the double / and \ is not allowed. So no luck unfortunate.

Comment: The directory in `username@domain:GitRepo/QRCode.git` points to `GitRepo/QRCode.git` inside the home directory. Do you know where the home directory is?

Comment: Could you try this? `username@domain:/c/GitRepo/QRCode.git` (there is a slash after the colon)

Comment: Partially [useful manual](http://fclose.com/b/linux/366/set-up-git-server-through-ssh-connection/) - "A basic git server through SSH tutorial" part with Windows-specific corrections

Comment: And [RTFM Git-URI docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html#URLS), don't mix two incompatible styles in one

Comment: I have tried "username@domain:/c/GitRepo/QRCode.git" also tried to put the repo in the users home folder without luck. I've used to ssh on my linux box without problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using `ssh://username@domain:...`?  I'm pretty sure you need to specify the initial scheme `ssh://` for the URI, otherwise git doesn't know how to access it.

Comment: I might have more issues in the URI. When I try to ssh from the git bash shell, I end up in C:\Users\User no matter what I put after :

Answer (score -3):

1. Forget for some time about Git-specific issues
2. Get, debug and fine-tune **pure SSH-login** to the box
3. When you get interactive SSH-session on the box - detect reached $HOME, relation to path to repos and correlation to URI - without it you'll do **NOTHING**

Use Brain, not ass!!!

Comment: I have forgot everything I know about git. I've tried to juse $HOME folder this is User/someuser on windows. But nothing helps - I don't think there could be more combinations I haven't tried

Comment: @DNRN - **don't use**, DETECT!!! **Read** my text! SSH to host, find directory, in which you appear

Comment: As I said I've tried.. I installed cygwin and now everything runs like a charm. Thanks for no help :)